# Very long initial loading (20sec)

Tags: performance

I am witnessing an odd behavior on a website I am currently developing – and I don't really know how/ where to look for the cause of that problem.

The problem only occurs after I haven't opened the page for maybe 4-6-8 hours – I'm not quite sure yet, what the time frame is. On the initial load the page takes about 20 seconds to display anything at all. Then it all runs rather smoothly.

Also the problem is really hard to track down since as I said after the initial "hickup" everything seems to run just fine. Also opening the page with a fresh browser window (empty cache/ history) the problem does not occur again which let's me think it must be server side.

The site has been in development for a couple of years now. It's basically an intranet page – and I use ACF and a few CPT to manage a rather large amount of data. It's basically a reservation system where you can reserve a time slot for various objects. So I did build some kind of calendar and first this thing was quite heavy. But i managed to reduce db requests to a minimum – and the calendar part runs rather smoothly now, once the page loads at all.

The problem occurs on basically every and any page i tested – even on the login page – and even on "Under Construction" screen before login.

It 'feels' as if a huge cache file had to be written first – but I don't have a cache plugin activated.

The site is running on a standard hosting environment at all-inkl, LAMP setup, PHP 8.1.

I hope, somebody had a similar problem and found a way to fix it.

Comment: there's not enough information here to formulate an answer, it looks like an open ended investigation. You'll need to identify the source of the problem before you can write a question asking how to fix it, so far all you have is the symptoms of 20s loading times. Install a plugin such as query monitor to identify what is happening during those 20s, disable any optimisation plugins such as autoptimise that bunch up all the output and send it right at the end, and check for HTTP requests and expensive queries. You should also do the standard practice of disabling plugins to identify the culprit

Comment: also, if there's a lot of data, especially ACF stored data, any query that tries to search the post meta table for values will be very slow and expensive, aka anything with `meta_value` or `meta_query`. Changing these to taxonomies will give _enormous_ performance gains as the post meta table isn't designed to search/filter/group posts, it's optimised for fetching values when you already know the post ID/meta key